# Selenium Python - How do I handle the exceptions on popups regardless of the order and handle a null or empty search

Tags: python, selenium

I have a search that is looping through a list.  I've added a try for the situations where the search requires additional clicks on the popups.  However, the order of the nested try, except causes an issue depending on which order the popups come in.  With the current code the application is getttng stuck on the optionModalContent popup.  Additionally, if a search is completed that is null or empty, the application will timeout.  What is the best way to handle the empty/null search?  Example would be searching C06 or 0.

Below is my code with a slimmed down version of the application.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait, TimeoutException
import time
appended_data  = []
classlist = ['C',
            'C01',
            'BETA BLOCKING AGENTS',  #optionModalContent
            'ANTIADRENERGIC AGENTS', #spellingModal
            'C02', 
            'C06',        #no search results timesout need to know how to handle this
            'C07',
            'Vitamins' #handled by optionModalContentTable    
            ]
time.sleep(1)
with webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe') as driver:   ## uses the content manager by using with webdriver.Chrome, improves performance

    for search in classlist:
            page = f"https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxClass/search?query={search}"
            driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe')
            driver.get(page)

            modal_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 4)
            try:
                modal_el = modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'synModalContent')))  ## handles last popup if the search isn't exact
                modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
                

                try:
                    modal_el = modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'optionModalContent')))  ## handles popup that requires you to select a line item
                    modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.uloption').click()   
                    
                except:
  
                    try:
                        modal_el = modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'spellingModal')))  ## handles popup to suggest spelling
                        modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
                         

                    except:
                        modal_el = modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'optionModalContentTable')))   ##handles first popup window on search if there are multiple classes for vitamin
                        modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
                        pass 
   
            except TimeoutException:
                pass        
            table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr.dbsearch')))
            classid = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table-responsive div.propText strong:nth-child(2)"))).text
            classname = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table-responsive div.propText strong:nth-child(1)"))).text
            classtype = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table-responsive div.propText strong:nth-child(3)"))).text
            filename = classname[0:30]+'.csv'
            df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[1].iloc[:,:-1].assign(ClassID=classid, ClassName=classname, ClassType=classtype)
            appended_data.append(df)
            driver.quit()
    appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
    appended_data.to_csv('testcategorization.csv')
```

I know my problem is going to be in my nested try except.  I've moved things around and added passes, but regardless of the order the application will eventually get stuck on one of the searches.  What is the best way to handle all of the popups regardless of the order?

Perhaps there is a better way to go about the try and except.  Additionally if the search returns no results, I'm not sure how to handle that.

The end result I'm looking for is to get my application to run without getting stuck on a popup that is in the list regardless of the order it's ran in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, this is what got me going:

Fetch the search key from current url, and subject the code to `if elif else` under `try` block. You may still improve it by using `try/except` in each `if elif else` statements.

```
title = driver.current_url
        print(title)
    try:
        if "BETA%20BLOCKING%20AGENTS" in title:
            modal_el = modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.ID, 'optionModalContent')))  ## handles popup that requires you to select a line item
            modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.uloption').click()
        elif "ANTIADRENERGIC%20AGENTS" in title:
            modal_el = modal_wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'spellingModal')))  ## handles popup to suggest spelling
            modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
            modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='optionModalContent']//li"))).click()
        elif "Vitamins" in title:
            modal_el = modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,
                                                                    'optionModalContentTable')))  ##handles first popup window on search if there are multiple classes for vitamin
            modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
            modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='optionModalContent']//li"))).click()
        else:
            modal_el = modal_wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'synModalContent')))  ## handles last popup if the search isn't exact
            modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
```

Still checking how to handle the `no classes found` condition. If I crack it, will post it here as update. Will check in my free time.
I would want to appreciate for the code that you wrote. It is very lean except that an additional browser instance opens, but I would say this is a very good one. I learned something today from you.

UPDATE:
I tried some alternatives and it worked. Please check this below code. It manages to get the result by search each item from the search list, while handling the `C06`.

I used a lot of print statements which I used for debug purposes. Feel free to remove them. Also, I used `time.sleep` in few occasions to have the alert handled. Try to reduce it and see if it works.

```
for search in classlist:
    page = f"https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxClass/search?query={search}"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(page)
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present())
        alert = driver.switch_to.alert
        alert.accept()
        print("alert accepted")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("no alert")
    title = driver.current_url
    print(title)
    modal_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 4)
    try:
        if "BETA%20BLOCKING%20AGENTS" in title:
            print("betablocker")
            modal_el = modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.ID, 'optionModalContent')))  ## handles popup that       requires you to select a line item
            modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.uloption').click()
        elif "ANTIADRENERGIC%20AGENTS" in title:
            print("diuretic")
            modal_el = modal_wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'spellingModal')))  ## handles popup to suggest spelling
            modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
            modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='optionModalContent']//li"))).click()
        elif "Vitamins" in title:
            print("vitamin")
            modal_el = modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,
                                                                    'optionModalContentTable')))  ##handles first popup window on search if there are multiple classes for vitamin
            modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
            modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='optionModalContent']//li"))).click()
        else:
            print("others")
            modal_el = modal_wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'synModalContent')))  ## handles last popup if the search isn't exact
            modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"No tables found in {search}")
        continue
```

Console Output (End result):

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

UPDATE 2: TO HANDLE TRY/EXCEPT per the comment of query creator.

```
for search in classlist:
    page = f"https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxClass/search?query={search}"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(page)
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present())
        alert = driver.switch_to.alert
        alert.accept()
        print("alert accepted")
        print(f"No tables found in {search}")
        continue
    except TimeoutException:
        print("no alert")
    modal_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 4)
    try:
        modal_el = modal_wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'synModalContent')))  ## handles last popup if the search isn't exact
        modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
    except:
        try:
            modal_el = modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.ID, 'optionModalContent')))  ## handles popup that requires you to select a line item
            modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.uloption').click()
        except:
            try:
                modal_el = modal_wait.until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'spellingModal')))  ## handles popup to suggest spelling
                modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
            except:
                modal_el = modal_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,
                                                                        'optionModalContentTable')))  ##handles first popup window on search if there are multiple classes for vitamin
                # modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
                modal_el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.nameEntry').click()
                pass
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent unfortunately on a smaller code set it will work, but I can’t hard code the exact search errors because there are thousands of searches in my file or data frame that contains the search that could be incorrect or misspelled, belonging to multiple classes, or multiple li.  There has to be a way to recognize the modal that provides the error regardless of the text.

Comment: Each one of those modal try’s works to catch the error on a single search that produces it if it’s the first search in the try

Comment: @user1470034 I appended a new code in my answer (UPDATE 2). I have handled the try except blocks, and also the C06 situation, but one thing I don't understand is when it gets to ANTIADRENERGICS, there are two modals opening - one into another (like in Beta Blockers). I am not sure if this is properly handled, for the buck stops there now. Please check my new updated code, and I hope it would be good to you.

Comment: Work's perfectly,   The problem was with how I had the try and except nested and then adding the alert,  I appreciate you Anand Gautam.  This has been quite a challenge for me.

Comment: Than you, and I admit it had been for me too. I have learned  a lot from this query today, and I must admit the way you wrote the code is awesome. I liked it. It's a different perspective for me in the limited knowledge that I have.

Comment: The spelling modal part at the end is another modal using LI's, but that's another problem outside the scope, I know how to handle it.